# insert into by select from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

table A :

```
ID | Name | Phone
```

ID (primary key)

table B :

```
tableaA_ID | Name | serial
```

tableaA_ID and serial (primary key)

the SQL statement :

```
insert into Table_B (tableaA_ID  , Name  , serial  )
select ID , Name , ( select  ISNULL(MAX(serial),0)+1 from table_B ) 
from Table_A
```

How the insert into by select data from another data works, dose it's works like for statement ?

because I  try to insert data into table B from Table A

But i get the error message Cannot insert duplicate key (ID , serial )=> (1,1)
because the serial always return the same values .

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting *one* maximum value in the `select`, which is causing the problem.  So, use `row_number()` to increment it:

```
insert into Table_B (tableaA_ID , Name, serial  )
    select ID , Name ,
           COALESCE(bb.serial, 0) + row_number() over (order by id)
    from Table_A CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(serial) FROM table_b) bb;
```

That said, this is usually an anti-pattern and you should be using an `identity`/`auto_increment`/`serial` or similar column to automatically assign the value.

Comment: Dear , why it's in my script not works fine ? suppose the table have two rows , when I try to insert the values into another tables the serial must be in first time 1 and in second time 2 , but why always return 1 ?

Comment: @QaisAlmomany . . . Your code doesn't work because the `max()` is executed *once* for the query.  The real solution is to use an `identity` column, though.